# Load items on ViewHolderAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, adapter, android-viewholder

I have implemented a `ViewHolderAdapter` to load items and display it on a `ListView`, but I want to display also a `AdMob Banner` in some rows. I have created a custom `Adapter` for two different `Layouts`. But the problem is that only display two rows, one for each `Layout`, when the item list is longer than 400 items.
Somebody can help me?

I show the code below:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]public class SubliguesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static List<Subligues> items;

public static class ClasGeneralViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    // Campos respectivos de un item

    public TextView subligue_name;
    public TextView created_at;
    public TextView members;
    public ImageView icon;


    public ClasGeneralViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        subligue_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_subligue_name);
        created_at = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_created_at);
        members = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_members);
        icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        String subligue_name= items.get(getPosition()).getSubligueName();
        // Launch RegisterUser
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                RegisterUser.class);
        // Pasar el nombre de la liga del usuario a RegisterUser.java
        intent.putExtra("subligue_name",subligue_name);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity) view.getContext()).finish();
    }
}

public static class BannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    // Admob banner
    public AdView mAdView;

    public BannerViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // here your custom logic to choose the view type
    return position %10;
}



public SubliguesAdapter(List<Subligues> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_banner, viewGroup, false);
            return new BannerViewHolder(v2); // view holder for banner items;
        case 1:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_register_existente_abierta_card, viewGroup, false);
            return new ClasGeneralViewHolder(v); // view holder for normal items;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            BannerViewHolder viewHolder2 = (BannerViewHolder)viewHolder;
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            viewHolder2.mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            break;
        case 1:
            ClasGeneralViewHolder viewHolder0 = (ClasGeneralViewHolder)viewHolder;
            viewHolder0.subligue_name.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getSubligueName()));
            String created_at = items.get(i).getCreatedAt().substring(0, items.get(i).getCreatedAt().length() - 9);
            viewHolder0.created_at.setText(created_at);
            viewHolder0.members.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getMembers())+" ");

            new ImageDownloaderTask(viewHolder0.icon).execute(items.get(i).getIcon());
            break;
    }


}

class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_team);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // here your custom logic to choose the view type
    return position %2;
}
```

I haven't run ur code but clearly this part is responsible for displaying different views in alternative `viewholders`, because you are taking `modulus by 2`, which will return you `0 for even numbers` and `1 for odd numbers`.

Do two things

- `return position % 10` will increase interval for ads you can give
  any number after which u want to put ad.
- Also to make it work perfectly with this logic change `case 0 to adview` and `1 to otherview`.

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thank you for your answer! I still getting only two rows when the list have more than 400 ítems. Looks like when display the adview, doesnt get anymore ítems.

Comment: have u switched the positions? Like 0 for ad and 1 for other one. Try it then see how many it will show.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, with that change now I have just get one row with the banner :(. I edited my question with the change code.

Comment: Hey Muhammad! It is working fine! The problem was in the layout!, I had match_content height in the banner layout and fill all the screen! Now is working perfectly! Thank you very much for your help! I give you the correct answer becouse it was ok from the beginning. Regards.